# Replacing an SQL dataset - select and update vs delete all and insert

Tags: sql

Say I have an SQL table of users like:

| user_id | dept_id | other_cols |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 1 |  |
| 654321 | 1 |  |

Each department updates this by sending an updated dataset of all their users (e.g. via an API). So I need to add any new users, update any changed columns for existing users and delete any old users which are missing from the latest dataset. There are no auto_increments, histories or related tables I need to worry about, I just need to ensure the table reflects the newly-supplied dataset for a given dept_id. I'm using MySql

Which approach is generally considered to be more efficient:

1. For each supplied user, check if it's already in the database and update it as necessary. Determine if any existing records are not in the new dataset and delete them

OR

2. Just delete all existing records and do an insert for each record in the new dataset

Or is the answer "it depends"!

I looked at [UPDATE vs DELETE and INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59441165/update-vs-delete-and-insert) but it didn't really help me

Comment: Sample new data and expected results would help immensely.

Comment: Unless you have historical requirements truncate/delete and insert seems to be the simplest thing. If you do have historical requirements it'd be a good idea to read up on Slowly Changing Dimensions (SCD) strategies. SCDII is common.