# Update vs Delete/Insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I looked at this thread: [In SQL, is UPDATE always faster than DELETE+INSERT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271641/in-sql-is-update-always-faster-than-deleteinsert), but it didn't seem to answer the question as everyone takes side on both.

Let's pretend I have a table with 100 columns and 50 million rows of data.
No indexes
No constraints

Would it be faster to truncate/insert 50 million rows or simply do an update based on column or combination of columns?

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29141391/10209642) Not exactly new but is still valid.

Comment: Very dependent on what percentage of the table is being changed. But why would you have a table with no indexes?

Comment: There are no absolute "answers" with respect to performance. The only way to know is to implement both and test/evaluate them.

Comment: I joined a company where they are growing their data department. Nobody knows how to use indexes other than me.